# connecting code in Python 3

Tags: windows, python-3.x

Is there a way to connect "if direction ==north:" to "if direction = south" without having to copy paste the code twice and take up more lines?

```
 direction = input('do you want to travel north or south?')

 if direction =='north':
  print('You chose North')
  print('An iron gate block your path')
  print('You need a bronze key to open it')
  print('You will have to go South')

if direction == 'south':
    print('You chose South')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('The path leads you to the Deep woods of Mirkwood')
```

Comment: There are different actions when direction is north than when it is south. There is only one common statement, do you want to connect them because of it? Or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to connect them because it would be much easier by deduplicating code

Comment: You must have two if statements if the actions are totally different.

Comment: If you're trying to refine your code you could create a map for points/direction choices and the appropriate string messages. 'Location'+'Direction', String

Comment: I do have the if statments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to define what you mean by 'connect'. Perhaps provide an example of what the output provides for a certain path.

If you want to show the south path after they have chosen north, you can add something like:

```
print('You will have to go South')
direction = 'south'
```

Otherwise, if you want the user to choose the direction again after picking north, place the choice into a loop similar to:

```
while True:
    direction = input('do you want to travel north or south?')

    if direction == 'north':
        #print statements
        continue

    if direction == 'south':
        #print statements
        break
```